# Not able to load a csv file using pandas pd.read_csv, multiple errors

Tags: pandas, csv, pycharm

I am quite new into the python programing / data scientist world. I use Pycharm and MacOs. For learning purposes I have downloaded some CSV files from Kaggle and I am always able to load them OK into Pycharm. But actually I not able to load a csv file from my work environment, surprisingly, I can load the file using R function 'fread', but my objective is to load it into python. Find below the code and the error:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
snowrawptp = pd.read_csv("/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/Desktop/SNOW raw data/SNOW PTP last year tickets_csv.csv")
```

Error:

> "/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/PycharmProjects/VCC SNOW project/venv/bin/python" "/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/PycharmProjects/VCC SNOW project/raw csv cleaning.py"
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/PycharmProjects/VCC SNOW project/raw csv cleaning.py", line 4, in 
>           snowrawptp = pd.read_csv("/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/Desktop/SNOW raw data/SNOW PTP last year tickets_csv.csv")
>         File "/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/PycharmProjects/VCC SNOW project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
>           return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>         File "/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/PycharmProjects/VCC SNOW project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 448, in _read
>           parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
>         File "/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/PycharmProjects/VCC SNOW project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 880, in **init**
>           self._make_engine(self.engine)
>         File "/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/PycharmProjects/VCC SNOW project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
>           self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
>         File "/Users/oscargonzalez-lliberosperis/PycharmProjects/VCC SNOW project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1891, in **init**
>           self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>         File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**
>         File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 678, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
>       OSError: Initializing from file failed

Thanks!

Comment: can you try this `snowrawptp = pd.read_csv(r"your_correct_path")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very sure but try removing spaces from your folders like 'SNOW raw data' and run again. Also is 'SNOW PTP last year tickets_csv' your file name or just 'tickets_csv'? Always try avoiding spaces in folders and files.